# Munin plugin does not have access to nginx logs

Tags: munin

I want Munin to graph nginx error codes, so I tried a couple of plugins I found:

- A Bash script:   https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/nginx/nginx_error
- A Python script:  https://gist.github.com/eykd/1107061

Both of them work fine if I run them manually as root, but not if they are run by Munin.  The problem seems to be that they try to access `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, and the user under which the plugins run does not have permission to do so.

I don't want to change permissions on `/var/log/nginx` or any of the log files.  I tried to give the scripts the setuid bit, and they both are owned by root, but that still does not make a difference.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add munin user to adm group. This is the default group which can access logfiles.

Comment: Thanks!  I found this:  http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q:CanImakethepluginrunasanotherusergroupthannobodynogroup, so now I can run the nginx_error plugin as root, and it works.